# GCP: IAM and BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

Could you please share your thoughts about this question?

You are configuring service accounts for an application that spans multiple projects. Virtual machines (VMs) running in the `web-applications` project need access to BigQuery datasets in `crm-databases-proj`. You want to follow Google-recommended practices to give access to the service account in the `web-applications` project. What should you do?

A. Give project owner for `web-applications` appropriate roles to `crm-databases-proj`.

B. Give project owner role to `crm-databases-proj` and the `web-applications` project.

C. Give project owner role to `crm-databases-proj` and `bigquery.dataViewer` role to `web-applications`.

D. Give `bigquery.dataViewer` role to `crm-databases-proj` and appropriate roles to `web-applications`.

Here is the [discussion thread](https://www.examtopics.com/discussions/google/view/25018-exam-associate-cloud-engineer-topic-1-question-116/).

Comment: NEVER use primitive roles (owner, viewer, editor). Thus, the answer is easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by guillaume, and outlined in [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic), basic roles (including Owner) should not be used in production environment:

> Caution: Basic roles include thousands of permissions across all Google Cloud services. In production environments, do not grant basic roles unless there is no alternative. Instead, grant the most limited predefined roles or custom roles that meet your needs.

Therefore, **D** is the correct answer.